# Is a representation of $\operatorname{SL}_n$ defined over a field $k$ if its image is contained in $\operatorname{GL}_n(k)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $f\colon \operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}_m(\mathbb{C})$ be an algebraic homomorphism such that $f(\operatorname{SL}_n(k)) \subset \operatorname{GL}_m(k)$.  Question: must $f$ be defined over $k$?  In other words, are the matrix entries of $f(x)$ polynomials in the entries of $x \in \operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ whose coefficients lie in $k$?

I'd also be interested in the question with $\operatorname{SL}_n$ replaced by other semisimple groups, but the above is the most important special case for what I am doing.

Comment: It suffices to prove the following, right? If $p \in \mathbf{C}[x_1,\dotsc,x_d]$ with $p(k^d) \subseteq k$, then $p \in k[x_1,\dotsc,x_d]$. For $d=1$ it is true. I don't know about the general case, though.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: doesn't the general case then follow from induction on $d$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: While that is a true fact about polynomials, it doesn’t imply the question since SL_n is not isomorphic to affine space.

Comment: @AndyPutman but $SL_n$ is not too far from being an affine space: the Bruhat decomposition produces a Zariski open subset isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^{n^2-1}$.

Comment: Sure SL_n is not affine space, but isn't it sufficient to consider the polynomials in the entries of $f$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg - yes, but you don’t know about what you get when you plug arbitrary values into them, just matrices with det 1.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger - that’s a good point, and allows an argument in the style of what Martin suggests.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger: I would say that the Bruhat decomposition produces a Zariski-open subset in ${\rm SL}_n$ that is isomorphic to ${\Bbb A}^{n^2-n}\times ({\Bbb G}_m)^{n-1}$, which is a Zariski-open subset in ${\Bbb A}^{n^2-1}$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, and in fact something much more general is true  Let $X$ and $Y$ be affine varieties defined over a field $k$. If the $k$-points of $X$ are Zariski dense, $X$ is reduced, and $f: X_{\mathbb C} \to Y_{\mathbb C}$ sends $X(k)$ to $Y(k)$, then $f$ is defined over $k$.

This was inspired by comments of Martin Brandenburg, Jef L, Andy Putman, and Piotr Achinger.

Proof: First note that by embedding $Y$ in affine space, we may assume $Y = \mathbb A^n$. Second note that by viewing a map to $\mathbb A^n$ as an $n$-tuple of maps to $\mathbb A^1$, we may assume $Y =\mathbb A^1$. Thus $f$ is a polynomial function in $\mathbb C[X]$, and we want to check it lies in $k[X]$.

Because $\mathbb C[x]= k[X] \otimes_k \mathbb C$, we may write $f = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_i$ where $\alpha_i \in \mathbb C$ and $f_i \in k[X]$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $\alpha_1=1$ and that the $\alpha_i$ are $k$-linearly independent. (Add $1$ to the list of $\alpha_i$s, then for any linear relation, use that relation to remove whichever $\alpha_i$ is not $1$ and adjust the $f_i$s appropriately.)

Now for $x \in X(k)$, we have $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_i(x)$. Because the $\alpha_i$ are $k$-linearly independent, and $f(x)\in k$, this implies $f_i(x)=0$ for $i>1$. Then because $X(k)$ is Zariski dense, this implies $f_i=0$ for $i>1$, so $f=f_1 \in k[X]$. QED

The Zariski density can be checked for $SL_n$ using the birational map to affine space obtained by forgetting one entry, and for other semisimple groups using the Bruhat decomposition as suggested by Mikhail Borovoi.

Comment: It seems that your proof works without the assumption that $X$ is affine.

Comment: Why is $k[X]$ a free vector space over $k$?

Comment: Why does every ${\rm Aut}({\Bbb C}/k)$-invariant element of $\Bbb C$ lie in $k$?

Comment: @Mikhail Borovoi 1. Every vector space is free. 2. Because $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed, every automorphism of a sub field extends to an automorphism of the field. Apply this to $k(x)$ if $x$ is transcendental or its Galois closure if not.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi New, slicker, proof avoids using any facts about automorphisms and thus avoids arguing with algebraic closures, transcendence bases, etc.

Comment: You write "a field $k$", but it should be "a subfield $k$ of $\mathbb{C}$", right?

Comment: At some point do we need the fact that $X$ is reduced (of course $SL(n)$ is, so this would only be relevant for the more general statement). I am thinking of $X= \mathrm{Spec}  k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$, $Y = \mathbb{A}^1$, and $f(\epsilon) = \alpha \epsilon$, where we could have $\alpha \in \mathbb{C} \setminus k$.

Comment: @Sarah: Any connected linear algebraic group $G$ over a field $k$ of characteristic 0 is unirational, and therefore, the set of $k$-points in $G$ is Zariski-dense. See Borel, Linear Algebraic Groups, 2nd ed., Corollary 18.3. By Will Sawin's proof, the answer to you question is Yes for any connected linear algebraic group $G$ over any subfield $k$ of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Replacing $\mathbf{C}$ with any algebraically closed field $C$ containing a given field $k$, this seems to work for $k$ an arbitrary perfect field.

Comment: @YCor Good point. I think my automorphism-free proof works even for imperfect fields.

Answer (score 8):

This follows from Theorem 6 in Steinberg's "Some consequences of the elementary relations in $SL_n$" in "Finite groups — coming of age", Contemporary Math. **45** Amer. Math. Soc. (sorry, I could only find a [Google books link](https://books.google.com/books?id=j3cr_NpG69UC&pg=PA515&lpg=PA515)), together with the remarks at the end of the proof.  Restricting $f$ to $\Gamma = SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$, the theorem yields a polynomial map $g$ (which is equal to $f$ for us) and a map $h$ that is trivial for us (since it is trivial on a finite index subgroup of $\Gamma$).  As remark (b) mentions, $g$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}(f(\Gamma))$, which is what you want.

Comment: In retrospect, this may have been a bit overpowered, since it does not use the algebraicity assumption.

Comment: This is really a special case of Margulis’s superrigidity theorem (though it takes some work to get from superrigidity to this, and possibly that work might require an anawer to the OP’s question).  For $\mathbb{Q}$, Steinberg’s theorem was first proved by Bass-Milnor-Serre, and for general fields it was proved by Ragunathan.

Comment: (all of these references only give the rational part, but that is the most decisive part — the finite order bit can be gotten from the rational bit in an elementary way).

Comment: @AndyPutman Thank you for these very interesting comments!